# Get the total count using Jquery in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is my structure of ul li

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Top Level </a>

    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Level 1_1</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a title="" class="grower OPEN">Level 2_1</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <a title="" href="#">Level 3_1 </a><span>(1)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a title="" href="#">Level 3_2 </a><span>(4)</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Level 2_2 </a>

                    <ul>
                        <li>    <a href="#">Level 3_1 </a><span>(5)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>    <a href="#">Level 3_2 </a><span>(1)</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Level 1_2 </a>

            <ul>
                <li>    <a title="" href="#">Level 2_1 </a><span>(3)</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>    <a title="" href="#">Level 1_3 </a><span>(2)</span>
        </li>
        <li>    <a title="" href="#">Level 1_4 </a><span>(1)</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have count of products shown along with the lower level of category. What I want is, show the total count against parent of each category using jquery.
I have no idea on how to do this.

Current System: http://jsfiddle.net/jvfwhs3f/1/

Required Output: http://jsfiddle.net/fz554136/

Comment: You can recursively go through your hierarchy, calculate sums and fill it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvfwhs3f/6/) of what I did.

Basically I added a class to all your spans with the count and looped through each li to add the total of each span within the li. But I'd recommend using a data attribute in your spans (`<span count="5">(5)</span>)` with the total count so you can parse the number directly with `parseInt($(this).data('count'))`

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var totalSpan = $this.find('span.green');
        var total = 0;
        $this.find('span.total').each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')); 
        });
        totalSpan.html("(" + total + ")"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: you dont need those replace calls or a data attribute `parseInt($(this).text())` will suffice  http://jsfiddle.net/z856u570/33/

Comment: No because in his spans, the count is in brackets. Therefore $(this).text will return "(4)" as a string.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. In that case, you could use `parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''))`  http://jsfiddle.net/z856u570/35/

Comment: Also, since you use `$(this)` 3 times, it would be best to cache it like `var $this = $(this);` ..... `$this.find(........` :)

Comment: Updated. Just by curiosity, does it affect the performance a lot?

Comment: In this particular function, no not a lot. But if you get in the habit of always doing this in your code, yes, it can make a significant difference across your application. Personally, I use the PHPStorm IDE which highlights any duplicated selectors in your code and lets you know that you could write it better, really cool feature IMHO